# Binding a value to a variable in another component in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angular 4 for my frontend. I am having a popup window and I want to pass a value to a different component from that popup window. I tried this method but its not working.

Here is my popup component.ts

```
GetApplicationDetails(cmp){

    this.SelectedCompanyCode = cmp.OBD_COMP_CODE;
    this.AddNewcomp.SelectCompanyFromPopUp(this.SelectedCompanyCode); 
    this.close(); 

}
```

here is my target component.ts

```
public SelectCompanyFromPopUp(comp){
 this.CompanyName=comp;
}
```

Here is my target component html page

```
  <div class="form-group FormComponents">
                    <label for="CompanyName">Company Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CompanyName" placeholder="Company Name" name="CompanyName" [(ngModel)]="CompanyName"
                        disabled>
                </div>
```

The method is working properly but the value is not displaying in the text box.
Please help me

Comment: Can you share a demo on stackblitz or plunkr?

Comment: You should probably use a common service between both components to retrieve/set the value.